# The total Wronskian

Tags: determinants, power-series

Given a sequence of function, $$F=\{f_1(x,t),f_2(x,t),f_3(x,t),\cdots,f_m(x,t)\},$$
we define the total Wronski determinant of this set of functions as
$$W(F)=\det\begin{vmatrix}F\\D_xF\\D_tF\\\vdots\\D_JF
\end{vmatrix},$$
where the order of the determinant is $m$, which equals the number of all possible derivatives with $ord\leq n$. That is to say, $m$ is cann't take all the number in $\mathbb{N}$.

For example, when $n=2$, $m=1+2+3=6$. We can take $F=\{f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_6\}$ and 
$$W(F)=\det\begin{vmatrix}F\\D_xF\\D_tF\\D_{xx}F\\D_{tt}F\\D_{xt}F
\end{vmatrix}.$$

> > My question is: Suppose that $f(x,t)$ is an analytic function, and $f_xf_t\neq 0$, then whether the determinant $W(\{f,f^2,\cdots,f^m\})$ is not identically zero?

Ps: There is a concept of generalized wronskian, and it is related to the linear independence of $F$. But it is not what I need.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Generalized_Wronskians

Comment: What if we let $\omega$ be an $(m-1)$th root of unity, and $f(x,t) = \omega^{g(x,t)}$ for some analytic function $g$. Then $f^m = (\omega^m)^{g} = \omega^{g} = f$. So the determinant is identically zero simply because two columns are repeated.